# Web accessible check mark

Tags: html, screen-readers, accessible

I need to add check marks (✓) to cells in a HTML table.

Can anyone tell me if using hex code is accessible, i.e. can it be recognised by screen readers? Or is there a more accessible way to approach this or is it impossible to create a web accessible check mark?

Answer (score 1):

The hex code will not probably be consistent between screen readers.

To be sure, you can set the check mark as an image and use the `alt` attribute:

`<img src="/check.png" alt="check">`

This way, all the screen readers will read this as "check".